# Datagrid selected row at a certain column as3

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flash-v3-components

I need to get the value of a certain column in the selected row via AS3, how can I do this?

It keeps returning null when I try `grid.SelectedItem.text`...

Thanks for the help! I need to be able to reference the column by name, in this case "ID".

EDIT: Does this require an event or something? Shouldn't there be a method for this built in? You'd think so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be a bit more specific ?

You can get get all the data you need from the DataGrid using the selectedItem.yourProperty.
Can you post a snippet that might make thing clear ?

Referencing a column by name is pretty easy:

```
myDataGrid.getColumnAt(myDataGrid.getColumnIndex('ID'))
```

The data is in the DataGrid's dataProvider, the column is there for other purposes.

Say you have an ID property added to the DataGrid:

```
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
for(var i:int = 0 ; i < 7; i++)
    dp.addItem({label:'label '+(i+1), ID:Math.random()});
myDataGrid.dataProvider = dp;
```

If you have setup a handler for the [CHANGE](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html#event:change) event, you should be able to get the data you need
through the [selectedItem](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html#selectedItem):

```
myDataGrid.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changed);

function changed(event:Event):void {
    trace('item at index ' + myDataGrid.selectedIndex + ' has ID: ' + myDataGrid.selectedItem.ID);
}
```

HTH,
George

Comment: Okay, now I need to get the value of the text in the selected row within that column.