# Select column in Flash datagrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid

When someone is using a datagrid, is there a default way (not involving extra coding) to select just one entire column?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selectedItem.specificProperty

Here's a posting with more info:

[can select column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096617/datagrid-selected-row-at-a-certain-column-as3)